# best way to convert timestamps to unix to find time delta, then put back to human readable format?

Tags: linux, bash, datetime

Real world example: using this (bash) tool to determine average time to backup databases in production.

Log format is:

```
YYMMDD HH:MM:SS
```

example:

```
140809 04:22:45
```

Making it into unix for easy subtraction isn't a problem. But how do I go about passing this along as an argument to the date command, and how can I put the diff into a hours, minutes, seconds delta?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out after RTM a bit more...

```
date_start=$(140802 12:23:20 )
date_end=$(140805 11:43:20 )

unix_start=$(date -d "$date_start" "+%s")
unix_end=$(date -d "$date_end" "+%s")
diff=$(($unix_end-$unix_start))

echo "the backup took $diff seconds to complete"
```